# Meteor file upload not working

Tags: javascript, meteor, collectionfs

I'm trying to upload images via Meteors CollectionFS but I'm not getting any errors in the client side code so I'm not sure what's broken. I see the console.log message "inside upload" but I don't see any success or fail messages from the Images.insert callback. Help.

`myproject/client/upload.html`

```
<template name="upload">
  <form>
  <input class="upload" type="file" id="upload" name=".../">
  </form>
</template>
```

`myproject/client/upload.js`

```
Template.providerblock.events({
  'click .upload': function(event, template) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var photo =  $('#upload')[0];
    var file = photo.files[0];
    console.log("inside upload");
    Images.insert(file, function (err, fileObj) {
      if(err) {
        console.log("unable to upload file");
      } else {
        console.log("file upload success");
      }
    });
  },
});
```

`myproject/lib/images.js`

```
var Images = new FS.Collection("images", {
  stores: [new FS.Store.FileSystem("images", {path: "~/uploads"})]
});

Images.allow({
  insert: function() {
    return true;
  },
  update: function() {
    return true;
  },
  remove: function() {
    return true;
  },
  download: function() {
    return true;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should:

1. Use `'change .upload':` instead of `'click .upload':`.
2. `Images` instead of `var Images` so you can use the variable in other file.

Comment: Thanks so much. That worked.  However, my meter app keeps restarting somehow b/c the client says it's modified. `=> Client modified -- refreshing`. Not sure what that is.

Comment: Not enough sleep. My app is refreshing b/c i'm storing images under the app directory which when modified causes the app to reload . So, I'll have to store via gridfs . Thanks!